# In office chat with persistent notifications

Tags: networking, chat

My production staff is predominantly and essentially Luddites by comparison. Most have never used email on the regular. While most people are chasing employees to get them to put down phones, these folks never even bring them. They are resistant to change but our building is large and we need a chat to ask the daily mundane questions without running across the whole building.

They use some systems but aren't at the screen 24-7. this causes strife over having to check machines for messages (2 separate computers). Short of installing a buzzer (these computers have no sound cards) or a big flashy light (their suggestion and I'm sure that's a ridiculous amount of tech hybridization) we want a chat app that has notifications in Windows 7 and 10 that must be dismissed and therefore stay persistent on top of other apps on the screen. Additionally, it would be nice if the app had the option of immediate and simultaneous PUSH to SMS so they can start carrying their phone (one does have a smart watch) and get on the fly notifications.

I started looking at apps, but notifications seem to be the least discussed thing in sales and marketing literature, yet almost every apps support is filled with requests about persistent notifications).

My hope is to avoid endless hours of forum searching on every app and crowdsource the answer from someone who already has or has had experience with the app I am looking for and just can't find.

Comment: I don't know about Windows 7, but notifications in Slack on Windows 10 stay in the notification drawer until you dismiss them.

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer now, but the Google Hangouts "Chrome App" notifications stay on screen until dismissed. However, if you aren't already using Google at work (G Suite), getting everyone on board may not be easy.

Comment: @MosheKatz Notification Drawer is apparently not enough, I need a popup that must be dismissed by a button click be it "ok" or "X'ing" out

Comment: The Google Hangouts popups meet that requirement.

Comment: @MosheKatz Can we use Google Hangouts totally separate as a chat program like slack without using the whole Google at work/suite?

Comment: If you create normal Google accounts for everyone or if you get them to use their personal accounts (if they have them), then you don't need to sign up for G Suite. However, managing that is probably going to be a major headache.

Comment: @MosheKatz Youre a solid guy, Moshe! Thanks so much!